# How do I bind Volume Up/Down/Mute and Brightness Up/Down keys in Lubuntu 16.04?

Tags: sound, keyboard, lubuntu, brightness, shortcut-keys

I just installed Lubuntu on my Lenovo Thinkpad 13 Chromebook using Crouton.  I have Brightness Down, Brightness Up, Mute/Unmute, Volume Down, and Volume Up keys on my keyboard that I would like to bind.  How do I bind these keys so that they perform there respective functions?

Is there any way of doing this just with the tools Lubuntu has out of the box?  As I am on a chromebook I would like to keep my install as minimal as possible.  If there is not a simple way to do so without downloading a tool I do not mind downloading a tool to help me accomplish this task.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, the keybinds are as follows:

brightness down

brightness up

pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle

pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -4%

pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +4%